# "Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string." error when importing gradle project in Android Studio 0.2.9

Tags: gradle, android-studio

*NOTE: i can't post links, so i guess you'll need to go [here](https://gist.github.com/nrser/b4c068fcd07d8be01b9e#file-references-md) to follow the references. sorry, not my rule.*

i'm getting the following error when attempting to import a project into Android Studio 0.2.9:

```
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 
'http://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/
gradle-1.8-20130830160653+0000-bin.zip'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty 
string. path='' basedir='<projects folder>/
drag-sort-listview/library'

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

the project was originally a Maven project (1). i opened it in Eclipse ADT, generated a `/librabry/build.gradle` file per the instructions at (2).

the Eclipse ADT generated `build.gradle` looked like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 7
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['']
            resources.srcDirs = ['']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

i had to change line 6 from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5+'
```

to get Android Studio to stop saying the versions were miss-matched. i also added a `/settings.gradle` file containing

```
include ':library'
```

and a `/local.properties` file with the contents

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.

# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
```

i then attempted to import the `/settings.gradle` file by selecting it in the 'File | Import Project...' dialog. i have 'Use Auto-import' checked and 'Use gradle wrapper with verification' option selected in the dialog (3). the full `idea.log` entry can be viewed at (4).

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This will happen if you are using `Environment Variables` like so:

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
```

And you have not defined those variables in your gradle.properties file located at the root of your project.

To fix this, make sure your variables are defined, here is an example from my gradle.properties file:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=app_keystore.jks
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=password
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=MyAppKey
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=password
```

Answer (score 3):

The error may be referring to your keystore's path. If the keystore's path doesn't work, it will think it's null. If you just want to use your keystore's file name (instead of the full path), make sure the keystore is in the root directory of your project.

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(**DoubleCheckPath**)
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> ok, solved it. the issue is with the empty lists under `android.sourceSets` in `build.gradle`, I commented them out to resolve the error. Here's my current `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 7
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            // java.srcDirs = ['']
            // resources.srcDirs = ['']
            // aidl.srcDirs = ['']
            // renderscript.srcDirs = ['']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

> hope that helps y'all.

Answer (score 0):

you may miss a file in project, for "gradle.properties" file, because this file is include some varies, for example , our custom var, such key.storefile key.keypassword, you should check this file is exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Modify file(String.valueOf(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)) in

```
android {
 signingConfigs {
 release {
     storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
     storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
     keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
     keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
```